# Why would map be much faster than unordered_map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

I implemented a search caching results that consist of keys of type State (a class with 7 short ints) and values of type `Score` (a class of 3 doubles.) Using unordered_map was at least 20 times slower than map.  Why?

Edit:  Darn it!  My hash function was

```
namespace std {
    size_t hash<State>::operator()(State const& s) const {
        size_t retval = hash<short>()(s.s[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < R; i += 2) {  // 1 3 5
            int x = (static_cast<int>(s.s[i + 1]) << 16)
                + (static_cast<int>(s.s[i]));
            hash_combine(retval, x);
        }
    }
}
```

I forgot to `return retval`, so it was all colliding!  I wish unordered_map had a hash_function_quality() function that reports the average number of collisions.

Comment: intel i5, gcc, 6 hundred thousand inserts and lookups

Comment: Are you using a hash function with unordered_map?

Comment: yes.  would it work if I wasn't?

Comment: For six-hundred thousand inserts I'd probably use a `std::map` still. It's just about 19 operations to access an element. Any computer performs 19 operations real quick. Even the prototypical computers from the 1950s.

Comment: It was actually UB to fall off the end of a value-returning function.  Gcc does have a warning for this, -Wreturn-type, which is included in -Wall.

Comment: The compiler I use gives a loud warning when a function doesn't return something at the end. Doesn't yours?

Comment: @Mark, I use cmake and I think it is hiding the warnings.

Comment: Awesome. you figured out how to use cmake as an IDE.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The speed of unordered_map is directly proportional to the speed of your hashing function.  It is never a straight forward relationship.  Case in point, if you use the simplest hashing function:

```
std::size_t myHash(MyObjectType _object){ return 1; }
```

then what you'll end up with is a collection which behaves like a list rather than a hashed container.  All the items will map to a single bucket and you'll have to traverse the entire bucket until you get to the item you desire (something that could take O(N) time.)

What you need to do is look at two things:

1. What hashing function are you using?  Does it cost a ridiculous amount of time to process?
2. How many collisions is it producing?  That is, how many unique elements are being mapped to the same hash value?

Either of those by themselves can and will kill the performance.

Comment: This is the answer that clued me in to what might be going wrong, so accepting it.

Answer (score 10):

`std::unordered_map` is commonly slow for a small number of elements because of the hash function. It takes a fixed (-ish) amount of time, but maybe a significant amount of time nonetheless.

`std::map` on the other hand is simpler than `std::unordered_map`. The time it takes accessing an element there depends on the count of elements, but less and less so as the number of elements grows. And the big-oh factor `c` for a std::map is commonly very small too, compared to `std::unordered_map`.

In general, prefer using `std::map` over `std::unordered_map`, unless you have a specific reason to use `std::unordered_map`. This holds particularly if you don't have a large number of elements.

Comment: Hard to believe that a hash function would take 20x longer than transversing a binary tree.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: The OP has provided no details of any kind on that.  Not only could the hash function take longer than expected, naive hash functions can generate lots of collisions.

Comment: @Fred, I do not follow you "no details of any kind." We're missing the access patern, true. Buy assuming typical collisions, 20x does not make sense.

Comment: @Fred, wait, OP say 600k inserts, then 600k Lookups, what further do you need?

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  I'll definitely keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Before the edit, all we knew about the hash function is that it operated on an object with 7 shorts.  Not literally "no details of any kind", but it might as well have been.  In fact, it was apparently exactly the collisions I mentioned that caused the problem.

Comment: @Fred, sorry, I did put some information in the comments below the question.

Comment: I find this answer a little misleading. One should rather compare a tree to a hash table, and it's respective usage scenarios, like sorted traversal vs unsorted, insertion and removal times. And then there are also compiler depending optimizations, e.g. some compilers treat an unordered_set as a vector as long as your keys are in a range of 0..50k.

Answer (score 8):

`unordered_map` uses a hash table under the hood, so most obvious reason why hash performs poorly is because you have too many collisions. You may consider using different, non-default, hash function that will give better results for your type of keys.

Answer (score 0):

For

> I wish unordered_map had a
>   hash_function_quality() function that
>   reports the average number of
>   collisions.

I think the following function might be helpful.

```
unordered_map::load_factor
    float load_factor() const;
The member function returns the average number of elements per bucket.
```

Lower the `load_factor`, better is the hash function.

Comment: I looked at the load_factor, but the problem isn't E[elements] over the buckets, but E[elements^2].